# Hard time with my Dice game

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a problem with my dice game. Every time I run it it says incorrect even if I guess the number right. There is the code, and a screenshot of when i got it right: https://gyazo.com/87400aab5747a05c77415a816952b26d

```
import random


ask = input(": ")


for i in range(1):
    dice = random.randint(1, 6)
    print(dice)

if ask == random:
    print("correct")
else:
    print("incorrect")
```

Comment: `input` returns a string, so it will never be equal to its numerical equivalent. You need `ask = int(input(": "))`

Comment: convert your input form str to int: `ask = int(input(": "))`

Comment: Beyond the answers showing the problem, the `ask == random` looks weird to me. Maybe it should be something like `ask == dice` ?

Comment: @aluriak I hadn't even noticed that as I just saw `input`. `for i in range(1):` doesn't really make sense either, it should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert `ask` to an integer, it will work fine:

```
import random

ask = int(input(": "))  # input returns a string

for i in range(1):
    dice = random.randint(1, 6)
    print(dice)

if ask == random:
    print("correct")
else:
    print("incorrect")
```

Answer (score -1):

That is probably because you read in something which by default will be a type string, and your number is an integer datatype. So "6" won't be equal number 6. You should do some conversion before the comparison if I'm right.

Comment: This is really ambiguous as an answer, the comments are clearer. _By default_ `input` will return a string. So you need to do `ask = int(input(": "))` but you don't include that.

Comment: I do not agree with the ambiguity, I think I clearly pointed out the problem. Just left the best solution to be figured out by the guy. Because based on the code I suppose he is learning the language, and I think the best way to learn is when you know the problem, you figure out the solution by yourself.

Comment: "That is probably because..." and "if I'm right". How did this elaborate on the definitive answer left in the comments that already explained this clearly _and_ gave the solution? In any case, this is a duplicate of a zillion questions.

Comment: @roganjosh I'm not a native English speaker, my wording could be better. But I can't see real ambiguity in my comment pointing to the problem.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me